# How to match the image width to screen size in swift ios

Tags: iphone, swift, uitableview, storyboard

Am  a beginner in ios. I was trying to make a list of images but i didn't find anything to set the table cell image width same as screen size. 
(Am using match_parent in android to achieve this)

Please take a look at the image:

[image]

Hope you understand my question.

Comment: means you want your image width is same as your cell width??

Comment: exactly @EICaptain. any ways to do tat|?

Comment: use autolayout....and pinned 4 sides with superview

Comment: am sry i dont kno. :(  could you pls tell me how to do that?

Comment: Use autolayout.  If you don't know autolayout, learn autolayout.  Autolayout cannot be taught in the space of a Stack Overflow q&a.  You need to find one of the many, many tutorials (and even those only teach autolayout in chunks).

Comment: check this tutorial...http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

Comment: any helpfull articles to learn tat?

Comment: Ok. thanks. @EICaptain

Comment: you can also check this tutorial...https://www.weheartswift.com/auto-layout-101/

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to add imageView to the cell container.

[image]

2. You fix size od the UIImageView and after that you have to adjust autolayout.

[image]

3. Set up autolayout to the left right top and bottom and click add constraints. Look that in every value (0) the the constraint is turned on (red line near the value).

[image]

4. Your image should now stretch horizontally. After that click the "update frames" in selected UIViewImage (Slected Views)

[image]